# How to conditionally set ServiceModel.EndpointAddress URI at runtime

Tags: vb.net, wcf-endpoint

I have a class in which the variable endpoint needs to be global (to other subs and functions in the class):

```
Public Class MyFirstVbNetClassEver
    Dim testEndpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://test.my.employer.com/ws/soap?wsdl")
    Dim productionEndpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://my.employer.com/ws/soap?wsdl")

    Public Sub Run()
        If (PRDOCUTION) Then
           Dim endpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(productionEndpoint )
        Else
           Dim endpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(testEndpoint )
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that ServiceModel.EndpointAddress has no constructor that accepts a parameter of its own type (i.e. "copy constructor").

Nor does it have a default constructor that allows setting the URI later.

What is the proper way of achieving what I want to do in VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't create a new one.  Use the one you already have:

```
Public Sub Run()
    Dim endpoint As ServiceModel.EndpointAddress = Nothing
    If (PRDOCUTION) Then
       endpoint = productionEndpoint
    Else
       endpoint = testEndpoint
    End If
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could keep the two endpoint addresses as strings rather than as `EndpointAddress` objects:

```
Public Class MyFirstVbNetClassEver
    Dim testUri As String = "https://test.my.employer.com/ws/soap?wsdl"
    Dim productionUri As String = "https://my.employer.com/ws/soap?wsdl"

    Public Sub Run()
        If (PRDOCUTION) Then
           Dim endpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(productionUri)
        Else
           Dim endpoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(testUri)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your 1st approach is what I just tried and seems to work. However, the syntax you posted will not compile as is, since ServiceModel.EndpointAddress does not accept `=`. My workaround is to declare `Dim endpoint` without anything after it. It works, but the compiler issues a warning *"Variable declaration without an 'As clause; type of Object assumed".*

Comment: Your 2nd approach works in C#, Java and C++, but not in VB.NET :)

Comment: Why do you say it won't work in VB.NET?  Both examples work fine.

Comment: In the 1st approach, Visual Studio yells "End of statement expect" at `Nothing`. In the 2nd approach, there are only 5 constructors and none of them accepts the type `ServiceModel.EndpointAddress`/

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Clearly you aren't copying my code exactly.  In the second example, I'm not passing the constructor an `EndpointAddress`.  In that example I'm passing it a `String`.

Comment: Oh you are right about the 2nd approach. Sorry about missing String thing. You are right about the 1st approach as well as I missed the omission of `New`.  Sorry, still getting used to this new syntax of VB.NET Accepting +1. BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2013.